# Opacity and image

Tags: css

The `img` opacity is interrupted by the opacity of the parent `div`. How to prevent this?

```html
<div class="parent_div" style="opacity:0.2">
  <p>Some text</p>  
  <img class="gif" style="opacity: 1;" src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/InsistentTautGodwit-size_restricted.gif"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color on the text using rgba instead as opacity is inherited.

```html
<div class="parent_div" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <img class="gif" style="opacity: 1;" src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/InsistentTautGodwit-size_restricted.gif"></div>
```